# Equivalent of FirefoxDriver(*profile*) for MarionetteDriver in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

I'm trying to convert some Selenium tests from `FirefoxDriver` to `MarionetteDriver`, but I'm hitting issues regarding PKI. My solution up to now has been to use various Firefox profiles which only have one custom PKI and automatically choose that for login purposes. However, it seems that the `MarionetteDriver` constructor doesn't have the capability to launch Firefox with a custom profile. How do I fix this?

I got around this in Python by having Python start Firefox before connecting to it with Marionette, but I don't know if Selenium WebDriver has this capability.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use `MarionetteDriver`. As it states in the documentation:

> /**
>    * An implementation of the {#link WebDriver} interface that drives Firefox using Marionette interface.
>    *
>    * @deprecated One should use FirefoxDriver with capability marionette = true or false respectively.
>    */

You should start a `FirefoxDriver` and enable marionette in the desired capabilities.

```java
DesiredCapabilities dc=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
Webdriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this results in Firefox crashing, likely due to this issue here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/2110

It's likely that your answer is correct, but for now I cannot mark it as such because it does not result in desired behavior.

Comment: @Inglonias I messed up with the capability name, could you try again?

Comment: I can use MarionetteDriver with desired capabilities, so I'll do that for now.

EDIT: Or not... It's just hanging now. Probably due to the fact that I changed the default Marionette port for that profile

Comment: That wasn't the issue. I don't know what the problem is, and the issue confuses me. Mozilla's documentation (which the issue I mentioned above links to) says that I'm to use `MarionetteDriver`

Comment: Works fine for me using FF48.